# It needs to draw an arbitrary number of boxes, across a user specified width, and allow for the "stacking"?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (length <= 20 || width <= 20) {
        System.out.print("Enter the length: ");
        length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Width: ");
        width = input.nextInt();

        for (int w = 0; w < length; w++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < width; l++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, in response to inputs:
    20
    2 * #
    5

We should get:

====================

```
 ***** ***** 
 *###* *###*
 *###* *###*
 *###* *###*
 ***** *****
```

====================

Comment: OK, is this a question?  Or a "please do my homework"?

Comment: Pro tip: indent by four spaces to keep your question text from being parsed as Markdown formatting.  Also, we can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong, what behavior/output you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: Its a homeowork  i ended up with this program i am unable to get an output like this 
I
 20
 4 * #
 5

====================

 ***** ***** ***** 
 *###* *###* *###*
 *###* *###* *###*
 *###* *###* *###*
 ***** ***** *****

 ***** 
 *###* 
 *###* 
 *###* 
 ***** 

====================

Comment: I am getting Enter the length: 2
Enter the Width: 3
 * * *
 * * *
Enter the length:

Comment: what i should add up in the code to get that kind of output

Comment: I'd say you need some kind of logic to figure out whether to print `#` or `*`.  How would you express this condition in terms of `l` and `w` (which, by the way, are terrible variable names)?

Comment: i printed # but still i am getting the output as   # # #
                                                   # # #
                                                   # # #

Comment: i need to print an output same as i posted above what i should add up in my code could you suggest me that.

Comment: I would suggest you move away from your computer for a moment, and figure out what kind of logic would tell you whether you need to print `#` or `*` for each value of `l` and `w`.  Then try to turn that logic into a set of Java `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: i ended up with * # # # #
 * # # # #
 * # # # #